# How do I ignore spaces at the end of the inputfile in C?

Tags: c, input, txt

I am dealing with a weird problem right now. Basically, my c-program receives a txt as input and I already know how long it should be. Therefore after reading it, I check for a EOF and exit successfully.
But if there are whitespaces after the text I won't get that EOF. In the textfile, the user won't notice the whitespaces obviously. How do I ignore the whitespaces? I guess I can't iterate over then because that could go on forever? The input is a LEN(gth) x WID(th) grid of the letter a and b(That's why I check for the \n).

```
for(i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < WID; j++)
            {
                    c = fgetc(infile);
                    if((c != 'a') && (c != 'b'))
                    {
                            return INVALID_INPUT;
                    }
                    board[i][j] = c;
            }
            c = fgetc(infile);
            if (!(c == '\n' || c == EOF))
            {
                    return INVALID_INPUT;
            }
    }

    if(fgetc(infile) != EOF)
    {
            return INVALID_INPUT;
    }

    fclose(infile);
    return VALID_INPUT;
```

Comment: Have another loop that keeps reading until `EOF` (VALID_INPUT) or a non-space (INVALID_INPUT) is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly need to check there is only whitespace left at the end, you have no other option then to iterate over it.

```
while (isspace(fgetc(infile))){}
if(fgetc(infile) != EOF) {
    fclose(infile)
    return INVALID_INPUT;
}
```

You will need to `#include <ctype.h>` to be able to use `isspace`. This loop will skip over all whitespace (like spaces, tabs and newlines) and stop at EOF or any non whitespace character.

Note that you also need to close the file in case of invalid input.

But the big question here is, do you absolutely need to check for other stuff following the regular input or not.